# paypal_adaptive gem undefined method to_sym for nil:NilClass in production but not in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm trying to develop a small app with paypal_adaptive gem, but every time I try to do this:

ipn = PaypalAdaptive::IpnNotification.new

It works on development but fails in production with mysql and this error:

NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/paypal_adaptive-0.3.2/lib/paypal_adaptive/config.rb:28:in`initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/paypal_adaptive-0.3.2/lib/paypal_adaptive/config.rb:69:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/paypal_adaptive-0.3.2/lib/paypal_adaptive/config.rb:69:in`config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/paypal_adaptive-0.3.2/lib/paypal_adaptive/ipn_notification.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in`new'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found out I was missing a line in the configuration file. It was a stupid mistake that I didn't see in my tests.